# Get values of array with dynamically named

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I'm getting dynamically the name of some File arrays, I can print the complete array, using

```
print_r($$n_v);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [name] => 5.docx [type] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document [tmp_name] => /tmp/php1cs872 [error] => 0 [size] => 14061 )
```

But if I try to do

```
print $$n_v['name'];
```

It don't works, how can I get the values of that array?

Comment: The fix is simple, but: don't use variable variables to begin with. Use an array, like `$data[$n_v]['name']`. That's much saner in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print it by doing the following by harnessing PHP's variable variable:

```
${$n_v}['name'];
```

Exert taken from the PHP variable variables page:

> Sometimes it is convenient to be able to have variable variable names.
>   That is, a variable name which can be set and used dynamically.

[**`Example`**](https://eval.in/242101)

---

<sup>*Read more about [PHP variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)*</sup>